# App opens with error message whenever I try to log in using a mobile browser

Tags: support, profile-page, mobile-app

I want to edit my profile. So I opened the site on Chrome. But when I want to log in, I can't. I get an error message:

> Sorry, we could not load question. Loading in browser instead...

...and then I see the same thing over and over again.

How can I fix this and log in on Chrome? I am using the SE app.

Comment: Is this about the iOS app? If so, are you by any chance using an iPhone XR? If not, which model iPhone (or Android device) are you using?

Comment: You chose at some point to make the app (either android or iOS) as the default app to open Stack Exchange pages. You have to disable this, so you can choose what to open links with, choose Chrome and it will work fine.

Comment: @Anonymous Hedgehog I'm using a Samsung J5(2016).

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance That's really not optimal behaviour. You shouldn't have to choose "open in app" 99.9% of the time just to enable basic tasks like *logging in*. Or, to put it another way, that's not a feature, it's a bug.

Comment: @Adeptus either way, it's now not relevant since there is no app.

Comment: Well I don't know about iPhone, but there's definitely an Android app, I'm using it right now...?